# Loop in PL/Postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, loops, plpgsql

I need help, trying to find why it goes to loop again when I run this function. It starts again after returning "OK" and it wont start with truncating the table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.table1()
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
DECLARE var schema.table2;
DECLARE s_doc text;

BEGIN

perform ssv('HTTPS', 'on');
perform ssv('SERVER_NAME', 'www.url.domain');
perform ssv('DAD', 'website');

truncate schema.table3;

for var in (
        select * from schema.table2
) loop
        if var.content like '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<XMLDoc format="XMLDOC-XML"%' then
                insert into schema.table3 (id, doc)
                values (var.id, var.content);
        else
                begin
                        s_doc:='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'||schema.doc2XMLDOC(var, '1');
                exception when others then
                        s_doc:=NULL;
                end;
                if s_doc is not null then
                        insert into schema.table3 (id, doc)
                        values (var.id, s_doc);
                end if;
        end if;
end loop;

return 'OK';
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION schema.export_doc()
  OWNER TO sysadm;
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, one of the three function calls before `truncate` does something you are not telling us:

```
perform ssv('HTTPS', 'on');
perform ssv('SERVER_NAME', 'www.url.domain');
perform ssv('DAD', 'website');
```

#### Edit: code audit

A closer look reveals quite a few issues:

- At the head you name the function `schema.table1()` (which is a weird name for a function), at the bottom you refer to a `schema.export_doc()`?
- You have the keyword `DECLARE` twice in the function header. You only need that once. To my surprise this does not trigger an error, though.
- If the `\n` in

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<XMLDoc format="XMLDOC-XML"%'
```

is supposed to be interpreted as a line break then you should use proper [syntax for escape string constants](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS):

```
E'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<XMLDoc format="XMLDOC-XML"%'
```

- You call a function `schema.doc2XMLDOC(var, '1')` further down. In mixed case notation? You are aware that [identifiers are cast to lower case](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) if not double quoted in PostgreSQL? I never use mixes case identifiers.
- The exception block looks suspicious. Why would the called function produce an error?

```
begin
   ...
   exception when others then
      s_doc:=NULL;
end;
```

There is a [number of tests you can run on your data](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PREDICATES) to prevent that:

```
xml IS DOCUMENT
XMLEXISTS(...)
xml_is_well_formed()
```

Cleaner and most likely faster than (slow) error handling.

Comment: Can it somehow affect the script so it would start looping without truncating?

Comment: @Marko: For instance if you call `schema.table1()` in `ssv`.